# When to use Q_NULLPTR?

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, null

I see `Q_NULLPTR` being used liberally in Qt source code and examples, but I have found no documentation for what it is exactly and when it should be used.

For example in this official [demonstration](http://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-5.6/qtserialbus-can-mainwindow-cpp.html) of the new Qt SerialBus module added in the new Qt v5.6:

```
if (!m_canDevice->connectDevice()) {
    delete m_canDevice;
    m_canDevice = Q_NULLPTR;
```

Did this serve the purpose of `nullptr` prior to that being added in C++11? If so, now that we have C++11, should I be using `Q_NULLPTR`?

PS: I tried searching the Qt source code for the definition of the macro but failed to find it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> Did this serve the purpose of nullptr prior to that being added in
>   C++11? If so, now that we have C++11, should I be using Q_NULLPTR?

Yes (somewhat) and No respectively.

C++ was quite lacking back in the days, so Qt had its own stuff, which later became obsolete as C++ caught up on the features.

That being said, `Q_NULLPTR` is (was) not functionally the same as `nullptr`, (as Andrei noted, if C++11 is supported it expands to `nullptr`) it didn't give you the type safety, just syntax "sugar". It illustrated the intent to the person reading the code, not to the compiler as `nullptr` does.

Answer (score 22):

`Q_NULLPTR` is a macro, that is replaced as `nullptr` if compiler supports c++11 and as `NULL` (which is replaced as `0`) if it doesn't. If you use c++11, you can write `nullptr` instead; use `NULL` if you don't.

Comment: [Here is the source code](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/global/qcompilerdetection.h.html#990) in case someone needs proof.

Answer (score 3):

Actually `Q_NULLPTR` had only one purpose: To allow use of `nullptr` without loosing support for compilers which didn't have C++11/C++0x support, as a direct use of `nullptr` would result in errors in such setups. The downside is that there are ambiguities of its fallback to `NULL` (or `0` in older Qt versions) which might result in unintended runtime behavior and limit the supported use cases compared to `nullptr`.

In the rare case that you target non C++11 compliant compilers, use `Q_NULLPTR` but make sure that the code works well when C++11 features are disabled. In all other situations `nullptr` is the better alternative as it results in compilation errors instead of buggy runtime behavior when used with legacy compilers. Qt 5.7 and later dropped the support for compilation without C++11 so there is no need for `Q_NULLPTR` if you depend on those versions.

There are other features like `qMove` or `Q_DECL_OVERRIDE` that give improved semantic when used on supporting compilers without breaking compilation on older compilers.

Answer (score 2):

Use `Q_NULLPTR` to stay compiler independent.

If you now decide to use `nullptr`, your code won't compile with an older c++98 compiler. If you decide to use `NULL`, you lose the c++11 type safety, even if available in your current compiler.

For the same reason macros like `qMove(x)` and the corresponding define `Q_COMPILER_RVALUE_REFS` exists.