# Replacement for Q_NULLPTR when backporting a Qt5 application to Qt4?

Tags: c++, qt4, backport

My application may be used on systems that are still defaulting to Qt4.x rather than Qt5.x and I was trying to do a "quick and dirty" port of a version that would compile/link and run with either major version of the libraries.  I was wondering what would be the *best* way to get around the absence of Q_NULLPTR in Qt4.x?  I saw the link mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36281426/4805858) SO answer which indicated the definition as:

```
#ifdef Q_COMPILER_NULLPTR
# define Q_NULLPTR         nullptr
#else
# define Q_NULLPTR         NULL
#endif
```

So should I just use a:

```
contains(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4) {
DEFINES += Q_NULLPTR=NULL
}
```

in my `qmake` project file?

Comment: Why use `Q_NULLPTR` at all and not `nullptr` in your application? Doesn't matter what version of Qt you use if you use a C++11 compiler.

Comment: I should perhaps rephrase it to say "The FOSS application I am contributing to" - we had started using Q_NULLPTR once we switched to Qt 5.x a couple of years ago - I was trying to find a way to get back to also being Qt4.x compatible and make as few changes as possible; and I am not convinced that the people using Qt4.x will be using a C++11 compiler (e.g. they may be on `gcc` 4.7 not 4.9)...

Answer (score 0):

`Q_NULLPTR` is Qt’s way to support both C++11 capable compilers as well as older C++98/03 ones. Do you actually need that level of sophistication? If not, then just use `NULL`, `0` or `nullptr` directly, depending on your compiler.

Otherwise things get more complicated because you need to detect the currently active C++ version. See edit below.

Of course you can always choose the easy way and use `NULL` or `0` which works in all versions of C++.

**Edit**

To mimic Qt5’s behaviour you could use this:

```
#if __cplusplus >= 201103L
    #define Q_NULLPTR nullptr
#else
    // not NULL to stay consistent with Qt’s convention
    #define Q_NULLPTR 0
#endif
```

Including a header just to have access to `Q_NULLPTR` isn’t terribly great, so you’ll probably want to define that macro in a *.pro* file. However, I don’t know how to detect the active C++ version with Qt4’s QMake.

Comment: However Q_NULLPTR __is not present in _Qt4.x___ hence my question - I think we were using a hard `0` in the past but I was not sure if that would be the best choice...!

Comment: Doesn’t matter that Qt4 does not provide `Q_NULLPTR`. It’s just a regular macro. There is no reason not to define it yourself when you build your own code against Qt4 builds, if you need the flexibility it provides.

Comment: Yeah, but __what__ is the best thing to define it to in that case - that is what I thought I was asking! 8-)  I was hoping that Qt might still define `Q_COMPILER_NULLPTR` even in Qt 4 - but I guess I will have to take a look and see...

Comment: That’s what I was trying to answer. :) Maybe that didn’t come accross clearly enough. Amended my answer.